# Join course id and score data derived from pivot query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to combine two arrays to form one result and to initiate another array to collect those data and insert to another table called report. My problem is how to combine two arrays and create another array to collect those data to insert into db.

```
$sum = array();
$subject = array();

$sqlquery = "SELECT student.userid, student.name, student.photo, finalresults.courseid, 
                MAX( CASE WHEN courseid = 'MATH' THEN marks END) MATH, 
                MAX( CASE WHEN courseid = 'HIST' THEN marks END) HIST, 
                MAX( CASE WHEN courseid = 'SCI' THEN marks END) SCI, 
                MAX( CASE WHEN courseid = 'GEO' THEN marks END) GEO, 
                MAX( CASE WHEN courseid = 'ENG' THEN marks END) ENG, 
                MAX( CASE WHEN courseid = 'CIV' THEN marks END) CIV, 
                MAX( CASE WHEN courseid = 'VS' THEN marks END) VS, 
                MAX( CASE WHEN courseid = 'KISW' THEN marks END) KISW, 
                MAX( CASE WHEN courseid = 'PS' THEN marks END) PS,
                MAX( CASE WHEN courseid = 'ICT' THEN marks END) ICT 
            FROM finalresults,student 
            WHERE student.userid = finalresults.stid 
              AND finalresults.terms = 1 
              AND finalresults.acd_yr = '2017' 
              AND finalresults.subid = '4'  
            GROUP BY finalresults.stid 
            ORDER BY SUM(finalresults.marks) DESC";

$res = $connect->query($sqlquery);

while ( $rows = $res->fetch_assoc() ) {

    $sum[] = $rows[ "CIV" ] .",". $rows[ "ENG" ] .",". $rows[ "VS" ].",". $rows[ "KISW" ].",". $rows[ "GEO" ].",". $rows[ "HIST" ].",". $rows[ "SCI" ].",". $rows[ "MATH" ].",". $rows[ "ICT" ].",". $rows[ "PS" ];

    $subject[] = $rows["courseid"];

}

for($i = 0; $i<count($sum); $i++) {

    print $sum[$i]."<hr/>";

    //output:
     92,  92,  92,  92,  92,  92,  92,  92,  92 
     82,  52,  52,  92,  52,  52,  92,  42,  22 
    ......
    ....
    ....

    //print $subject[$i]."<hr/>";

    //from i need something like 
     Phy 92,Chem  92, Math  92, Hist  92
    .......................................
    ..............
}
```

Comment: Show the DB structure

Comment: @Auris 1:M relations student->result

Comment: When you create the string you insert into your `$sum` array - why can't you concatenate the subjects there?

Comment: Not that descriptive rly. I have a feeling that your problem is not how to combine the arrays, but the actual query itself. You are getting all the course results in one row (per student I assume), but you are only getting one course name (courseId) per row. I suggest that you get one coursre/student per row that way you can combine them like: `$array[$row['userId']][$row['courseName']] = $row['score']`

Comment: @thebluefox because he does not have the names for the courses there (he could hard code them ofc, because the fields in DB are hardcoded anyway)

Comment: @Auris - precisely my point - OP __does__ know the names of the courses as they're tied to the column names from the database.

Comment: Well hardcoding is one way, personally i would just make this work dynamically, but that requires more tinkering with the query

Comment: @Auris I don't understand how to set this $array[$row['userId']][$row['courseName']] = $row['score'] ??

Comment: in order for this to work you first have to update your query. If that is too complex for you, use `thebluefox's` suggestion and just hardcode the names in your array.

Comment: @thebluefox, like this   $sum[] = $rows['marks']."-".$rows['courseid'];

Comment: @Auris, $sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM student,finalresults WHERE finalresults.stid = student.userid";